# Were deportations committed by Stalin during WWII covered in Allies' press?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, russia, stalin, caucasus

Was the deportation of the Chechen and Ingush populations  (carried out in 1944) covered in the media of the Allied powers?

Comment: You should include the research you've already done to prevent others just repeating information you already know.

Comment: it was  a lot harder to know about such things, and to report them in a timely manner back then

Comment: How would they know?

Comment: A lot of things Stalin tried to keep secret got out at some point.

Comment: @NeMo - Perhaps, but "at some point" it becomes more of an interest to historians than journalists.

Comment: Here is a suggestion: Take a look at the book "The Moscow correspondents: reporting on Russia from the Revolution to Glasnost" by Whitman Bassow, specifically Chapter 5 about the reporting from USSR by foreign journalists during WWII (you can borrow the book for free from https://archive.org/). You will get a pretty good idea on restrictions imposed by Soviets on their movement and on what they could report and what subjects they wanted to report about.